# passing string with segue causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm trying to pass a string from a `ViewController (VC)` to a `CollectionViewController (CVC)`
I have a `UIButton` on VC with a triggered segue of `show` linked to the CVC.
In my VC, i have `prepareForSegue` as follows

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"gotoImages"]) {
        CQTaskPhotosCVC *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.queueID = _idCode;
    }
}
```

in my CVC.h

```
@interface CQTaskPhotosCVC : UICollectionViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *queueID;
@end
```

and heres the error i get

> 2016-02-02 12:05:45.015 CactusQueue[41739:6063627] -[UICollectionViewController setQueueID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12836e410
>
> 2016-02-02 12:05:45.017 CactusQueue[41739:6063627] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController setQueueID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12836e410'

I've passed data between VC using segues before and I've never come across this issue. removing `vc.queueiD = _idCode;` doesn't result in a crash so i don't know if I'm just overlooking something stupid or what.
what do?

Comment: Are you sure you set in your Storyboard in InterfaceBuilder the correct class to your `UIViewController` to `CQTaskPhotosCVC`?

Comment: that was is. god i need some coffee.... or sleep. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error:

```
[UICollectionViewController setQueueID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It says that a object of class `UICollectionViewController` is calling a method `setQueueID:` that it doesn't know.

So, your real issue is that in your Storyboard, you didn't set the custom class `CQTaskPhotosCVC` to the `UICollectionViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Check at the right side in interface builder, if you have entered CQTaskPhotosCVC as class in the custom class section:

[image]

Comment: as @larme pointed out, that was the problem. this is why you don't code with lack of sleep.